# How to check all the form fields were given to enable the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I need to `enable` the submit button, only when all the Input values were given.

I have a form like the below in my blade file.

```
<form method="POST" id="contactForm">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""/>
     <div class="error">Error Message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""/>
     <div class="error">Error Message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
     <textarea name="body" id="message" rows="5"> Enter your message</textarea>
        <div class="error">Error message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="primary" id="buttonSubmit" disabled/>
   </div>
</form>
```

Added the **required attribute** inside the controller.

**In controller:**

```
public  function store()
{
$data = request()->validate([
         'name' => 'required',
         'email'   => 'required|email',
         'body' =>  'required',
        ]);
}
```

The problem is, even if I add the **name field** and click the **button** , the submit button is **disabled** on click.

The button should be **disabled**, only when all the input fields were given.

**Script:**

```
 const button = document.querySelector("#buttonSubmit");
 const buttonExpirationDataKey = 'button-disabled-expiration';
 button.addEventListener("click", () => {
   var form = document.getElementById("contactForm");
             var fields = ["name", "email","body"];
             var i, l = fields.length;
             var fieldname;
             for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
               fieldname = fields[i];
                if(form[fieldname].value  !== ""){
                  button.disabled = true;
                  let now = new Date();
                  let expirationTime = 1000 * 5; // 5 secs to disable the submit button
                  let expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expirationTime);
                  localStorage.setItem(buttonExpirationDataKey, expirationDate);
                  button.dataset.enabledAt = expirationDate;
                }
                 else {
                   button.disabled = false;
                }
               return false;
              }
            });
```

The for loop iterates over each input element, if the **particular input element** have a value and then If we click the **submit**. The button is **disabled** and stored in the local storage.

How to check all the **form input** and the **textarea** has values and then after clicking the **submit button**, the button should be **disabled** for 5 secs.

https://jsfiddle.net/1vgzj8oc/

How could I do this? Could anyone please help?

Comment: just us `required` attribute on `<input>` HTML element, no need for Js... for example: `<input required type="text">`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Comment: I've added the validation in the controller, Do I need to add it in the input field too?

Comment: Don’t forget that regardless of any client side validation you perform, you’ll still want to validate on the server.

Comment: @Peppermintology, So, I need to add the validation on html(client side) and in laravel(server side)?

Comment: Correct. Never trust input that you don’t have control over. Client side validation such as what you’re implementing can be circumvented. Also the required attribute doesn’t validate the type of the field or whether it’s value is what you expect for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the required attributes to the HTML

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" required/>
```

But if you choose to do it with jS, you can do it this way...

```html
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="requiredInput"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="requiredInput primary" id="buttonSubmit" disabled/>
```

```js
const requiredInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".requiredInput");
requiredInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  // Logic
});
```

Comment: forEach(function(input), here function(input) where input is the input field?

Comment: Do I need to add the `required` attribute in the html? Adding the validation in controller is not needed?

Comment: You can add the required attribute directly into the HTML,
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" required/>
Like that.

Comment: Adding the required attribute in the input field didnt work.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: After adding required attribute to input, If i click the submit button. The button is again disabled. I've added the required attribute to all the input fields, but, still If I give the value for `name` input and the other two(email and textarea) values ==="". The submit button on click, gets`disabled`. How could I do this? Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add required attribute.  added link for reference
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required]

```
<form method="POST" id="contactForm">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" required/>
     <div class="error">Error Message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" required/>
     <div class="error">Error Message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
     <textarea name="body" id="message" rows="5" required> Enter your message</textarea>
        <div class="error">Error message</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="primary" id="buttonSubmit" disabled/>
   </div>
</form>
```